# How to create a personalized workout for non-responders to 3s x 5-12r? (goal size and strength, aesthetics)

Tags: routine

Why I ask? Because in articles and studies about "non-responders" to "normal workouts" in resistance training, they say that a personalized workout does indeed lead to much more growth in both categories than with a normal r/fitness plan. 5x5 workout etc. <- Standard routine. Not personalized.

Don't say "pay a PT". Internet should have tutorials how to make such routines. For free. Let's say the person trained for 6 months and his results were 2 chin ups, 5x5x5 push up, 0 dips, 2x2x2 inverted rows with rings and so on. So very small progress in short.

And what is a non-personalized workout? Something like the workouts which you can see in r/fitness and r/bwf? Would training with high volume because it makes me progress much faster be a personalized routine? Why is a normal workout routine not personalized, if humans are identical? 
2 Humans can have same muscle/fat ratio but one can have up to 25% more strength, despite having same muscle/fat/water ratio.

The only thing I know of is increasing volume if you gain only slow with the typical 3 sets and 5-12 reps, but this leads to bigger exhaustement of the body, and humans cannot tolerate that for long. So what should one do?

**What is the most likely parameter to be changed to see normal gains within non-responders? Increasing the volume and decreasing the frequency? Buw how do I recover from sooo much volume?**

I don't want you to create one for me, so info about me should not be relevant.
And if you answer with:Just change sets, reps, resting time between sets until you see 1kg/2lbs muscle per month: This is confusing for me. To track everything down. Confusion! And I can't even know when I gain 1 kg per month.

Comment: "Don't say "pay a PT". Internet should have tutorials how to make such routines. For free." - it does, in a lot of places. "if you answer with:Just change sets, reps, resting time between sets until you see 1kg/2lbs muscle per month: This is confusing for me.". This is why you pay a PT, you pay them for their experience and expertise in writing programs specific to you. Why do people hire builders to build houses when you can just learn it yourself? There's plenty of guides on line...

Comment: Please understand that your question isn't answerable, as your premise is wrong - "Non-Responders" are not a real thing. Once you let go of the idea that your body somehow works different than that of every other human being, Mark Rippetoe has all the answers: https://www.amazon.com/dp/0982522754/

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger premise is wrong, because one can increase it's "fitness" level despite making very slow size and strength gains? very funny.
are you just telling me that my body is my handicap and i have to accept that?

Comment: What? I'm telling you that the training cycle of 'stimulus-regeneration-supercompensation' is the same for every human. Some get buff by just looking at weights, some are unlucky and have to work real hard for even the slightest gains. But there's no "It doesn't work for me this way".

Comment: On a side note: It isn't clear from your question how you utilize chinups and dips. As a benchmark to see if you've gotten stronger (or lighter!) every few weeks or so, they are fine. But they are a poor choice of regular excercise if you can do 0-2 reps max. Better substitute with rows and triceps extentions.

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger I don't mean that it's not working at all. But if you gain only the slightest gains, you're an non-responder.  If you would be a BOSS of a company would you take the guy who learns and works the slowest? You wouldn't. Because he isn't worth it. He is a non responder to everything. :( 
Bodyworkout exercisse have progressions. There are chin ups progressions with less intensity and everybody can do them.  Like negatives. Or with Bands. 
Here you can see my inverted rows progress: https://pastebin.com/dVJNjYEz
Doesn't look good or?

Comment: I can't really make much sense of what you write. Again, there's no such thing as a "Non Responder". An effective workout for you would look roughly the same for you as for anyone else. If you struggle to make any progress at all, it's most likely because your routine is poor, you're not compliant to the routine, you have poor eating and sleeping habits, or a combination of all three.

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger My routine is made by educated people. I follow the routine strictly. I'm not daily in a kcal surplus. Sleep more than 8 hours. I don't see what I do wrong. Except if beginners need kcal surplus. I did that once, i got fat. nothing else.I don't think I need a surplus until I cna do 3x12 chin ups.

Comment: @Stjema -- it sounds to me like you're frustrated with your progress and as such the question reads more like a frustrated information dump than a well-formulated thought. There are too many points to comment on. Can you focus your question?

Comment: @C.Lange Hm. Okey. I trained calisthenics with goal of increasing of muscle mass for 6 months without making normal progress. Results were 2 chin ups, 5x5x5 push ups, 2x2x2 inverted rows and other very tiny numbers. Then I googled and found out about non-responders who don't make progress with "normal workout routines", despite doing everything right. Now I'm here. Non-responders = People who gain only little with a standard routine.
Of course I am venting if I do everything right and I get nothing back.

Comment: @Stjema -- I think your question is: "I have been doing a calisthenics workout for the past 6 months and have seen very little progress. What am I doing wrong?" I personally believe you're too focused on this "non-responders" idea. Edit your question to include the program and diet you've followed for the last 6 months. Also, can you clarify what 5x5x5 pushups is? (5 sets of 5 reps, 5 times?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [6 months in calisthenics and still almost no progress](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40375/6-months-in-calisthenics-and-still-almost-no-progress)

Comment: @C.Lange ive already asked that question as you can see. And I did not get any help there. Just "eat sleep and train". Very rude.
it means 3sets a 5 reps. Thats how you say those things in weightlifting too. Nothing special to calisthenics.

Comment: "Thats how you say those things in weightlifting too." No one I know ever used that. The common way to express this is '[sets] x [repetitions] x [weight]', or just '[sets] x [reps]' for bodyweight excercises. Seems like I'm not the only one confused by your notation.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the most likely parameter to be changed to see normal gains within non-responders?

TL;DR: Sleep 8+ hours a night, eat high quality food concentrating on protein and fibre, drink enough water, find ways to keep stress to a minimum.

---

I'll give you three that people often overlook:

- Sleep
- Diet (and hydration)
- Stress

One of the biggest jumps I had in body composition, as well as strength, was when I stopped travelling every weekend to see friends; which would mean not sleeping properly for 3 night, and eating crappy food for 3 days (takeaways, eating out, protein bars, etc).

Are you sleeping **at least** 8 hours a night? Is it quality sleep? Are you constantly waking up at night? Are you staring at your phone or the computer until 3am?

I understand that life can get in the way, especially if you've got kids, but lack of sleep is probably the main factor that impact most people's training.

My optimal evening routine looks something like:

- 2100: Make breakfast for the following day
- 2110: Stretching out hips / chest
- 2120: Cold shower
- 2130: Read in bed until I start to fall asleep (normally about 15 minutes)

My phone automatically switches to "Do not disturb" mode at 2130, and the only time I touch it after that time is to plug it in, or very occasionally check the alarm if I've been travelling.

Food wise, I'm a big believer in quality over quantity. Eat good quality food, eat a lot of vegetables, eat grass fed beef and free roaming chicken and eggs. I like Dan John's approach to diet, eat like an adult and concentrate on more protein and more fibre (that means more protein rich foods and more fibre rich foods, like vegetables, **NOT** supplements). Eat organ meats, like liver, kidney and heart, they contain a lot of nutrients that people tend to miss these days with the preference of eating muscle meats.

Drink enough water. How much is enough? I like to aim for 1 litre per 25kg of bodyweight. That means I drink, on average, 4 litres of water a day (plus a few cups of black coffee).

Stop drinking energy drinks completely and cut fizzy drinks (soda in the US) to a minimum. Yes, I do enjoy the occasional can of Coke (never could completely shift that sweet tooth), but I have maybe one a week, if that.

Finally? Chill the f**k out.

Stress will screw up your body in a lot of ways, like screwing up your sleep (which can have a scary amount of impact on your health).

How do you reduce stress? I can't tell you that, you need to figure out what's causing it and address those issues. If you need help with it, then go talk to someone professionally, there's no shame in it. I've done it. A lot of people I have a great deal of respect for have done it.

Again, what works for me is spending time with friends (but not all weekend, forfeiting sleep and food), being outside in nature (I rock climb, and yes, I find hanging off a rock face a hundred feet in the air by my fingertips relaxing), cold showers every evening, and sitting quietly with a coffee and a good book (basically, spending time in my own company).

But but but... what about sets and reps and exercise selection and rest periods and reverse Bulgarian tricep curls on a Swiss ball!?!?!?

If you're not recovering, the nothing is going to work past a certain point. Yes, you need to stress the body to enable adaptation to take place, be it muscular hypertrophy or strength, but if you're not allowing your body the chance for the adaptations to take place, you won't progress.

Want a personalised plan?

Every day for the next 6 weeks, do this:

- Be in bed by 2200 (10pm) in a dark room no electronics in the same room (no red light from the TV, no phone on charge next to your head)
- Take a cold shower before bed
- Sleep through until at least 0600 (6am). If you can get away with it, don't set an alarm but allow yourself to wake up naturally
- Eat 10 - 15 portions of vegetables, concentrating on things like broccoli, cauliflower, leeks, onions, garlic, beets, leafy greens, squash and sweet potatoes
- Drink 1L per 25kg of bodyweight
- Eat enough high quality protein, ideally from organ meats from grass fed animals (I can't remember the recommended amount off the top of my head, but it's easy to find, if you're vegan, find other protein sources that aren't soy based, though fermented soy is ok)
- Get outside in nature, go for a walk through. If you get the opportunity, go swim in the sea or a lake
- Spend time with friends. If you can't do that physically every day, then just send a message to let them know you're thinking about them, I like to send stupid comments and jokes, because I like making people smile and laugh
- Spend a little time by yourself. If you're into meditation, then do that. If you're not (I'm not), then go sit quietly and read for 10 minutes (note: playing on your phone doesn't count, turn the stupid thing off)
- Lastly, go train. Lift weights or do bodyweight stuff, it really doesn't matter that much, just pick a routine and stick to it for the next 6 weeks. I'd recommend the StrongFirst Simple and Sinister kettlebell routine, though I doesn't exactly match your goals

Comment: I sleep 8h and more. Random sleep duration. Going to bed after midnight. Not waking up much. I am on screens the whole day.
I wake up without alarm.

I get 0.8g protein per lbs, and more than 40g fiber per day. 
I drink 4 and more liters per day.
I don't consume shit like energy drinks.
I am chill. No stress in my life. I meditate sometimes. 
My recovery should be 100/100 as you can see.
There is almost no research that soy protein powder is bad. 90% of it says it's good as long as you dont eat 200g soy isolate per day.
@Dark Hippo

Comment: The only things I don't do is going to bed before midnight, having real good friends, reading books made of paper...
sigh.......

Thanks for trying to help me though. 

Any other ideas?

What you mentioned is I think not important.
Important is to talk about non-responders. They had no gains until they did high volume. If you are non-responder you don't need to have a good stress life balance. haha. First you need gonna respond to the fucking weights you lift. :@

Comment: @Stjema Ok, good luck.